# How to create capturing groups in regular expressions?

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to use Regex to classify groups of data dependent on how many sectors are within an array. E.g.:

```
group = One journey
group|group = Two journeys
group|group|group = Three journeys
```

Could someone tell me the best practice way to do this please?

**EDIT:** Apologies but I'm pretty new to RegEx and still trying to work things out. I don't know which language I'm using but the tool I'm building these into is Adobe Analytics - using the Classification Rule Builder.

Also, this question has been marked as duplicate but I can't say I found the other thread particularly helpful.

I've also tried experimenting using Regex101 but still can't get my head around this. Thanks.

Comment: What language/tool are using for your regex?

Answer (score 1):

For such a case you need to capture what you want to match inside some block that would depend on the language you are using. For example, if you are using `Python` you can use:

```
(\w+)
```

This regex will allow you to capture and count every repetition of word characters, that is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, that will be able to capture all the text you have between pipes.

By the way, in order to test your regex and to do some basic training and trial-error approach you can use tools like [this one](https://regex101.com/).